# Reading custom property in a processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am trying to create a custom processor (with Java) in Apache Nifi to read the user's custom property. Is it possible to create a processor to extract the user key value pair? If so, how should I go about extracting them?

Are the user custom properties stored within a dictionary in a library of some nifi.processor.*?

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

Ideally, I want to extract the dynamic values of **Property** and **Value** for all inputs above. ie. {"Custom Property 1": "Some value", "Custom Property 2": "Another Value", "Custom Property 3":"Third Value"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user-defined properties are available in your ProcessContext like all properties are, but they have a flag for being `dynamic`. Here's a snippet for iterating over the user-defined properties:

```
context.getProperties().keySet().stream().filter(PropertyDescriptor::isDynamic).forEach()
```

Fill in the lambda in the `forEach()` with your logic for handling the properties.